# AWS Configuration History

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

How do I monitor changes to Lambda or API Gateway configuration? for example when someone changes the memory settings, updates the code or changes API resource and etc. Is there a built in admin log?

Comment: Yes, CloudTrail and AWS Config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For seeing resource history/versions you can use AWS Config where you have a nice overview of the timeline.
In case that you need to automate something based on changes or get some alert, you can achieve that with AWS Config notifications: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/notifications-for-AWS-Config.html